# Dynamic routes in rails with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a set of pages with public attribute. I want the routes file handle dynamic routes but only for public pages.

I currently have the following, but there is no restriction, all pages are visible. What I'd like is go to page only if page is public else raise 404.

```
Page.public.each do |page|
  get "/:slug", controller: 'pages', action: 'show' if page.public?
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code is (was missing 'Not Found')

```
class PagesController

  before_filter :is_public, only => [:show]

  protected

  # Check if the page is public, otherwise raise a routing error.
  def is_public
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless Page.find(params[:slug]).public?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put this behaviour in the controller rather than in routes.rb, since a page could change from private to public during runtime and routes in production are initialised only once at the start.

```
class PagesController

  before_filter :is_public, only => [:show]

  protected

    # Check if the page is public, otherwise raise a routing error.
    def is_public
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new unless Page.find(params[:slug]).public?
    end
end
```

Comment: Good point. No change required in current routes declaration?

Comment: The current declaration would create an a route '/:slug' for every page object, so I would replace it with just `get '/:slug', controller: 'pages', action: 'show'`. Or just `get '/:slug' => 'pages#show'`. I assume that the slug param is some kind of parameterised unique name which will identify a page when given to Page.find

Comment: It raises error in controller in is_public method     wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: Thx but it still raises 500 when Page is not public. Same error ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/exceptions.rb:10:in `initialize'